# I don't know how to write a hangman game in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C programming. I have two problems!
1. When I take the input of char by using the command `guess = getchar();`it takes the input for the first time but skips the next time the loop runs! That's why i used an array to store the character entered by user!
2. My code runs fine but I don't know how to print the Hangman in this game. Any idea? 
Regards!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define interface for (int a = 0; a < 50 ; a++) printf("*");
#define space for (int a = 0; a < 15 ; a++) printf (" ");
void MENU()
{
    interface;
    printf("\n");
    space;
    printf("Welcome to HANGMAN GAME!\n");
    interface;
    printf("\n");
    space;
    printf("Rules\n- Guess a single letter!\n- Number of lives are 5 in number!\n");
    printf("- Wrong guess will cause you to loose one life!\n- Repetition of a letter will cause you to loose a life!\n");
    printf("- To quit in middle of the game. Type in quit!\n");
}
int main(){
    int wordlength, index, oldcorrect;
    char guess;
    srand(time(NULL));
    char guesschecker[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    char guessword[][10] = {
        "windows",
        "cupboard",
        "sharpener",
        "lifeguard" };
    char letterguessed[10];
    int correctguess = 0;
    int lives = 5;
    int loopindex;
    int quit = 0;
    MENU();
    index = rand() % 4;
    wordlength = strlen(guessword[index]);
    /*
    printf("\nindex: %d word : %s wrodlength : %d\n", index, guessword[index], wordlength);
    */
    while (correctguess < wordlength){
        printf("\nHangman word: ");
        for (loopindex = 0; loopindex < wordlength; loopindex++)
        {
            if (guesschecker[loopindex] == 1){
                printf("%c ", guessword[index][loopindex]);
            }
            else printf("_ ");
        }
            printf("\n\nLetter correct so far : %d", correctguess);
            printf("\nEnter your guess letter : ");
            fgets(letterguessed, 10, stdin);
            if (strncmp(letterguessed, "quit", 4) == 0){
                quit = 1;
                break;
            }
            guess = letterguessed[0];

            printf("Your guess is : %c\n", guess);
            oldcorrect = correctguess;
            for (loopindex = 0; loopindex < wordlength; loopindex++)
            {
                if (guesschecker[loopindex] == 1){
                    continue;
                }
                if (guess == guessword[index][loopindex])
                {
                    guesschecker[loopindex] = 1;
                    correctguess++;
                }
            }
            if (oldcorrect == correctguess)
            {
                lives--;
                printf("Wrong guess!\n");
                if (lives == 0)
                    break;
            }
            else printf("Correct guess!\n");
            printf("Your lives left are : %d", lives);
        }
        if (quit == 1)
            printf("You quit early!");
        else if (lives == 0){
            printf("Sorry You are out of lives!\n");
            printf("The correct word was : %s", guessword[index]);
        }
        else printf("You Won! Yayy!");
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you take the input in this program?

Comment: @ShauryaChats ,Via the `fgets`

Comment: Does fgets() return a line or a character?

Answer (score 1):

1. Just add `getchar();` after `guess=getchar();` to fix it.
2. You'll have to do that manually using several `printf`s and `if`s

Comment: I added another getchar(); but the problem seems to persist! Kindly if you could write that part of the code for me. It'll be helpful!

Comment: And do you input more than one character? If so,replace the `getchar()` with `int c;while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);//note the semicolon here`

Comment: No, I only input one character and the problem persists! And yes I know this code to get the string input!